# Delete table rows based on values from another table with MySQL40 in PHP

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

**"Delete Resources that have never been hired"**

There are 2 tables of concern: `resource_line` and `resource`.

so far i have come up with this to no avail:

```
 DELETE 

 FROM resource 

 INNER JOIN resource_line ON resource_line.fk1_resource_line_id = resource.resource_id 

 WHERE resource_line.fk1_resource_id <> resource.resource_id
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must select from multiple tables separated by comma, and use the `where` clause instead of the `on` to link them, because older versions of Mysql didn't support delete with inner join:

```
 DELETE resource.* FROM resource, resource_line 
 WHERE resource_line.fk1_resource_line_id = resource.resource_id 
 AND resource_line.fk1_resource_id <> resource.resource_id
```

Ref:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html

Comment: Hi David, thanks for looking at this. I have run the suggested script and now recieve the following error:

#1054 - Unknown column 'resource_line.fk1_resource_line_id' in 'where clause'

What i need to be able to do is DELETE all of the rows from the resource table WHERE resource.resource_id <> resource_line.fk1_resource_line_id

with the asumption that <> is 'not equal to'

Any ideas?

Comment: Had a bit more joy with this (i.e. no error message)

DELETE resource.* FROM resource, resource_line 
 WHERE resource_line.fk1_resource_id = resource.resource_id 
 AND resource_line.fk1_resource_id <> resource.resource_id

However it didn't delete any rows...???

Comment: Sure it didn't delete any rows. Now in your where clause the fields in the '=' expression are the same as in the '<>' expression. This will always return 0 rows. I gave you the correct syntax for your type of query, which is what you were asking for, but I cannot help you with the fields that you need to put in each expression without nowing the tables schema.